# Armature is resetting it's y position every time I open the blend file

Tags: armature

For whatever reason, the armature ends up pinging off downwards whenever I open up the blend file, applying transformations, setting origin point, does nothing. The armature is where it needs to be in edit mode, however
Here's the blend file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hp4gV7TZas9mHoBjiBhDD1f62L0QtY3x/view?usp=sharing I really don't want to close the file incase I want to add anything else

Comment: Bones are keyframed down there.  Select your rig, then select all keyframes on your timeline with 'a' and delete.  Now you can reset position etc on your bones and it'll preserve through save/load, render, frame change, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't even realize there were any keyframes